# R Shiny app : bold text inside shiny.fluent::Text (Microsoft Fluent design)

Tags: html, r, shiny, fluent

very quick question : how can I set text passed to the `shiny.fluent::Text` function to render bold ? more generally, how to pass styling options to this function ?

In the [help page](https://appsilon.github.io/shiny.fluent/reference/Text.html) of the function, it is written

> You can specify the variant prop to apply font styles to Text. This variant pulls from the Fluent UI React theme loaded on the page.

but I don't understand how to use this `variant` parameter.

I have tried setting `class=ms-fontWeight-bold` at different places and play with the `variant` parameter but I found nothing working...

Sorry, surely newbie's question but I am new to Fluent and I find the `shiny.fluent` package quite poorly documented (maybe because I am too unexperienced...)...

Thanks in advance for any help

Reproducible example :

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny.fluent)


ui <- fluentPage(
  tags$style(".card { padding: 28px; margin-bottom: 28px; }"),
  uiOutput("analysis")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$analysis <- renderUI({
    Stack(
      horizontal = TRUE,
      tokens = list(childrenGap = 10),
      div(
        # << how can I set this text to be large ??????????????????
        Text("Test", variant="large")# , class = "ms-fontWeight-bold" ### does not work
      )
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the text to be displayed in a `div` with the desired class:

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny.fluent)


ui <- fluentPage(
  tags$style(".card { padding: 28px; margin-bottom: 28px; }"),
  uiOutput("analysis")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$analysis <- renderUI({
    Stack(
      horizontal = TRUE,
      tokens = list(childrenGap = 10),
      div(
        Text(
          "Test",
          variant = "large"
        )
      ),
      div(
        Text(
          div(
            class = "ms-fontWeight-bold",
            "Test"
          ),
          variant = "large"
        )
      )
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: perfect :-) thanks a lot, I definitely need to improve my html skills...