# R shiny.fluent customising

Tags: r, shiny

Building an app with shiny.fluent as the framework and cannot figure out how to change a card colour. As it over-rides bootstrap, I'm working off a custom card function and have tried both inline and external css to change its colour.

I've tried putting in the custom function, tried referring to the class style in the card in main UI, tried wrapping the output in the server section with a div and specifying inline css as per
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77071662/r-shiny-app-bold-text-inside-shiny-fluenttext-microsoft-fluent-design)

I've followed all the tutorials available online but none are going near customising a card or GridItem.

Here's the various ways I've tried:

On server side:

```
  # create a reactive to sum totals and return for range within chosen dates
  output$total <- renderText({
    div(
      class = "ms-fontWeight-bold bg-primary",
      data <- data(),
      sum <- data %>% group_by('Total Generation') %>% 
        summarise(Sum_Total_Gen = sum('Total Generation'))
```

In UI inline:

```
    GridItem(class = "bg-primary ms-sm12 ms-xl4",
         Card(title = "Date Filter", filters(),
              div()
         )
```

Or...

```
ui <- fluentPage(
  tag$style(
    div{
      color:red;
    }
  ),
  Grid(
```

In UI linking external stylesheet in a www folder as specified in docs

```
ui <- fluentPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "styles.css")
  ),
  Grid(
    GridItem(class = "ms-sm12 ms-xl8",
```

In custom card function:

```
Card <- function(..., title = NULL){
  Stack(
    class = "ms-depth-6",
    style = "color:red;",
    tokens = list(padding = 10,childrenGap = 10),
    if(!is.null(title)) Text(title, variant= "medium"),...
  )
}
```

New to fluent ui but also shiny fluent. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in housing the CSS file in www folder within src folder containing ui, global, layout, server functions